# Weird behavior of reference to vector.back() after vector is modified

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, reference

Let's start with this sample code in C++:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        const auto &x = vec.back();
        std::cout << "Before: " << x << ", ";
        vec.push_back(i);
        std::cout << "After: " << x << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code is compiled with `g++ test.cc -std=c++11 -O0` and below is the result:

```
Before: 0, After: 0
Before: 1, After: 0  
Before: 2, After: 2
Before: 3, After: 3
```

I was expecting the second line of output to be

```
Before: 1, After: 1
```

since `x` is reference to an item in the vector, which shall not be modified by appending items to the vector.

However I haven't read the disassembled code or done any other investigations for now. Also I don't know whether this is an undefined behavior in the language standard.

I want this to be explained. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) can cause reallocation, if we look at the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `23.3.6.5` *vector modifiers* says:

> void push_back(const T& x);
>
> void push_back(T&& x);
>
> > > Remarks: Causes reallocation if the new size is greater than the old capacity. *If **no** reallocation happens, all the iterators **and references** before the insertion point remain valid*.

we can see that [back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back) gives us a *reference* and so if there is a reallocation it will not be *valid* anymore.

Answer (score 4):

`vector` iterators (and previous references to elements) can possibly be invalidated after the vector is modified. Using them is unsafe.

Comment: Sorry but there is nothing related with iterators.

Comment: @starrify: Try getting a copy instead of a reference to the value behind `back`.

Comment: @KirilKirov Yes that's also what I suspect, and I want to make sure that's the problem (by quoting the standard or reading the generated assembly code or whatelse)

Comment: @BenjaminBannier Well that would be the way I use to avoid this problem. In the real code (the code I provide above is just a sample) items in the vector are structs whose size maybe large, and that's why I chose reference instead of value copy.

Comment: @starrify then you might want to avoid the reallocation overhead, and you should size your array accordingly. If you do a `vec.reserve(100)` beforehand, this problem should go away, as long as you stay within 100 elements.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Yes that's exactly what I've written in the code just now! Thx :)

Comment: @starrify It sort of does, because `vector` iterator and element reference invalidation rules happen to be the same.  Which makes lots of sense, as both element references and iterators to `vector`s are typically implemented as dressed-up pointers...